# Ubuntu Linux 14.04 LTS Server Edition information need

Tags: 14.04, server, ram, cpu, lts

I was wondering what's the maximum RAM, and maximum CPUs does the Ubuntu Linux 14.04 LTS Server Edition can handle. I found a server computer I want to buy, which is a SuperServer 4048B-TRFT. I don't want to over buy something that; something  else doesn't support, or can handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Linux runs most of the TOP 500 supercomputers you can be fairly sure that "normal" servers should not be a problem.

Comment: Linux, for the win. :)

Comment: Also, RAM should (in theory) be around 2^64 byte (64bit version), which is about 18450000 TB, according to [wolframalpha]. I don't know much about CPUs, but server cpus are as far as I know well (and officially) supported, since linux the most common OS for servers.

[wolframalpha]: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2^64+byte+in+tbyte